# 2 times higher or 2-times higher?

Tags: british-english

which of them should be preferred in academic British English?

> 2 times higher

> 2-times higher

and would how to write a ranging difference

> 2-3-times higher

Comment: How about two times higher or twice as high?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Times = used to show the difference in amount of two things, by multiplying one of them by the stated number
>
> ”My foot swelled up to three times the normal size when it was stung by a wasp.”
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/times)

There is no need to form a compound term “two-times” in such context. (Do not be diverted by the tempting analogy with *two-timer*, which is an accepted idiomatic term for adulterers and others.)

From this argument I would always edit “2-times” to “2 times”.

To indicate a range, “2 to 3 times ...” clearly indicates a number in the range from 2 to 3, without the slight suggestion of ambiguity that 2-3 may be an arithmetic expression (with value -1), and without the weird idea of a compound term or notion composed of the disjoint elements “2”,”3”, and “times”.

Comment: I hardly think that an expression "2–3 times higher" would ever be interpreted as "–1 times higher", and indeed when writing 2–3 in an English **text** rather than a maths exam would ever be read that way.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Indeed, but I did use the word "slight".